# MySql Join Query two tables

Tags: mysql, join

hi i am trying to join two tables using mysql query and for which i am unable to retriev the data

two tables  are accountheader and accountheadermonths.

query:

```
Select ah.AH_SUBNAME,ahm.AH_OPENINGBALANCE1 
from erp_updated.accountheader ah,erp_updated.accountheader_months ahm 
where ah.AH_CODE =" " AND ahm.AH_CODE=" " ;
```

thanks in advance
please help

Comment: That's not `join` it's [*cartesian product*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)

Comment: first try to select all the columns like `Select ah.*, ahm.*`. When your join would work, you'll specify exact columns.

Comment: @alfasin: well, it _is_ a join if `AH_CODE` is identical in both tables: a join doesn't have to use the `join` keyword. But it's a funny way of doing it. Usually, I'd see `where ah.AH_CODE = " " and ah.AH_CODE = ahm.AH_CODE`.

Comment: In any case, questions should always have expected and actual behaviour. This question is lacking the latter. What happens when you do it? Error? Wrong data returned? No data returned? That sort of thing.

Comment: No it's not considered a `join` unless you add the following condition to the `where` clause: `AND ah.AH_CODE = ahm.AH_CODE`

Comment: Check If in your tables there are rows with `ah.AH_CODE =" "` and `ahm.AH_CODE=" "`: `select * from erp_updated.accountheader ah where ah.AH_CODE =" "` and `select * from erp_updated.accountheader_months ahm where ahm.AH_CODE=" "`

Answer (score 4):

For joining two tables you should have a common to join the two tables

```
Select ah.AH_SUBNAME,
       ahm.AH_OPENINGBALANCE1 
from   erp_updated.accountheader ah 
join
erp_updated.accountheader_months ahm 
on     ah.<col>=ahm.<col>
where  ah.AH_CODE =" " 
AND    ahm.AH_CODE=" " ;
```

Comment: could you please edit your question, with what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

In any join query, you have to specify the conditions which joins multiple tables. Looks like AH_CODE is the key which relates two tables in your case.  So, query will be

```
SELECT 
   ah.AH_SUBNAME,
   ahm.AH_OPENINGBALANCE1 
FROM
   erp_updated.accountheader ah, 
   erp_updated.accountheader_months ahm 
WHERE
   ah.AH_CODE=ahm.AH_CODE
   AND ah.AH_CODE =" ";
```